# How many courses is my party wall?

Tags: attic, attic-conversion

I'm about to embark on a loft conversion for my ~1960's bungalow. This will be a full width dormer.

After doing to reading and research, I'm pretty sure I'll need some steel work. The steel would need to rest on my side of a party wall.

However, my party wall is pretty thin and I'm not entirely sure if it is a single skin or double skin. Is there any easy way I can check this?

Comment: Have you tried asking the adjoining neighbor? They might know (single vs double skin, not how to check...)

Comment: They moved in after us so wouldn't know.

But I did find an interesting article that might help:

https://www.markmcnee.com/brick-wall-thickness/

If I get time today, I'll take a picture of the brick pattern and see if it reveals anything

Comment: A "course" is a horizontal row. That doesn't seem to be what you're asking.